# AttributeError: 'KerasTPUModel' object has no attribute '_ckpt_saved_epoch'

Tags: python-3.x, tf.keras

I am training a keras model with google colab TPU. My code ran successfully on CPU and GPU before. However, when I changed the code to the TPU version, I met some error.

Here is my transform code:

```
model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
model,
strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
    tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
```

Here is my compile code:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3), 
loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The error happened when I ran the following code:

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=64*8,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

The error:

> AttributeError: 'KerasTPUModel' object has no attribute
>   '_ckpt_saved_epoch'

Thank you advance for your help

Comment: I am running into a similar issue, did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In my script, I resolved this error by downgrading Tensorflow from 1.14 to 1.12